# JavaScript: Call private function within attribute's event listener

Tags: javascript, oop, object, closures, dom-events

What's the best way to call a private function within an attribute's event listener function?

The JavaScript object:

```
function dog() {
    /* dog's private attribute: noseButton */
    var noseButton = $("#dog-nose-btn");
    noseButton.click(function() {
        // bark();
    });

    /* private function bark() */
    function bark() {
        console.log('woof!');
    }
}
```

So what's the most suitable way to call the `bark()` function within noseButton's click event listener? Closures?

Comment: What are the other ways/approaches to do so ? What drawback you found in that ?

Comment: Actually I don't know any other ways except closures. How would you do it? Drawback: just looking for the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass some parameters to your function like this:

```
function bark(args1, args2) {}
```

Then you should call it into the context of click:

```
noseButton.click(function() {
        // bark();
    });
```

Otherwise, if only one parameters will pass, you don't need to do this:

```
noseButton.click(bark)
```

With this way, if you use this single argument, it will be interpreted as event.

So the anwser is, it depends on how many parameters you will pass.

Comment: You're right (in case of one parameter). Clear fallacy. So my current issue is solved. Thanks Radonirina.

But what exactly do you mean with "call it into the the context of click" (in case of several parameters)?

Comment: `click(function() {
     bark()
})`
And `function() {}` into click is one context

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var dog = (function() {
    return {
        bark: function() {
            console.log('woof!');
        }
    };
})();

function dog() {
    /* dog's private attribute: noseButton */
    var noseButton = $("#dog-nose-btn");
    noseButton.click(function() {
        // bark();
        dog.bark();
    });

}
```

the Closure is safe and recommended practice how to handle private section of the code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: What if you have several object properties, for example "wag"? So you would list them comma separated in the return?
In Java there's one object / one class, but here is the class (function dog()) and additionally the variable var dog. That's why I'm trying to keep any object related stuff within the dog class.

Comment: Yes, all additional functions and properties you can specify as key : value pairs. and separate them by comma. essentially you are returning js object from the Closure.